# Using jQuery to apply function on a specific Div generated by EJS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have coded a series of bootstrap collapsible Divs using the Javascript `forEach` function in an EJS file. These divs all have a button to expand and collapse the div. Initially, pressing on any button will expand all divs but I have managed to overcome that by indexing the IDs of those divs.

My problem now is I have a separate JS file running jQuery. The jQuery is used to hide and show specific font-awesome icons. When the div is collapsed, it shows an arrow-down icon and hides the arrow-up icon. When a div is expanded, it shows an arrow-up icon and hides the arrow-down icon. My jQuery when activated will apply the changes to all divs but I only want to apply it to the div that I clicked. I briefly recall I could use `$(this)` but haven't been able to find anything that could help me with it.

Please see my JS and EJS files below.

list.js

```
$('#collapsibleDivBtn').on('click', () => {
    var downHiddenStatus = $(".fa-caret-square-down").is("[hidden]")
    var upHiddenStatus=$(".fa-caret-square-up").is("[hidden]")
    $(".fa-caret-square-down").toggleClass('hidden')
    $(".fa-caret-square-down").attr('hidden',!downHiddenStatus)
    $(".fa-caret-square-up").toggleClass('hidden')
    $(".fa-caret-square-up").attr('hidden',!upHiddenStatus)
});
```

list.ejs

```
<!-- Start of the page -->
    <div class="container mt-3">
        <!-- Title of the page -->
        <h3>List of Racks</h3>
        
        <% data.forEach((rack, index) => { %>
        <div class="card mb-3" >
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <div>
                        <h5 class="card-title"><strong><%= rack['Cabinet ID'] %></strong></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a id="collapsibleDivBtn" href="#collapsibleDiv<%= index %>" class="btn p-0" data-toggle="collapse">
                            <i class="far fa-caret-square-down text-primary bg-white"></i>
                            <i hidden class="hidden far fa-caret-square-up text-danger bg-white"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"><%= rack['Abbreviated Address'] %></h6>
                <hr>
                <div id="collapsibleDiv<%= index %>" class="collapse">
                    <div class="row mb-2">
                        <div class="col">
                            <p class="card-text">User Status: <br />
                                <span id="siteStatus" class="statusUpdate" ><%= rack['User Status'] %> 
                                </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="col">
                            <p class="card-text">Site Status: <br />
                                <span id="userStatus" class="statusUpdate">Online 
                                    
                                </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <p class="mb-0">After Service Status: <br />
                                <span id="aft_service_status" class="statusUpdate">Unknown
                                    
                                </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% }); %>

    </div>
```

Comment: insert is here link to font-awesome, pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for hiding elements. Just use CSS rotate for your icons.

```js
$(".container").on("click", function(){
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass("arrowUp");
});
```

```css
.container{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.container i{
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.arrowUp {
  transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a class="container">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="container">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="container">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine here. But once I move it over to my project, it just doesn't work. I haven't added in the relevant CSS animation yet. But when I inspected the element, the arrowUp class just doesn't show up.